# Usar Variável externa no JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript

Bom dia!

No site da empresa que trabalho, tem certas variáveis como essa: {{order_total}}

No caso, preciso fazer um script simples, pra pegar o valor total e adicionar um HTML na frente...

```
 $JQuery(function(){
var valordopedido = {{order_total}};
if(valordopedido >= 299){
    $JQuery('<div class="msg-free_shipping"> <p><span class="warning">ATENÇÃO:</span> Comprando mais <span class="restante">R$259,10</span> você aproveita o <strong>FRETE GRÁTIS</strong> nas compras acima de <span class="valor-gratis">R$299,00</span></p> </div>').insertAfter('form#cart_update_post');
}});
```

Só que fica dando o erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Alguém conseguiria ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade isso não seria uma variável, e sim uma expressão. Você está usando algum framework? Estas expressões podem ser tratadas como variáveis dentro de seus escopos na parte de negócio, não na parte da view. Mas especificando qual linguagem está usando e se está usando algum framework, fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: O site é desenvolvido em cima do Magento, Gabriel!

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro está avisando que a sintaxe `{{order_total}}` está errada, que não deveria ter o `{` ali.

Se a variável existe no escopo em que você está basta utilizar assim:

```
var valordopedido = order_total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando tem essas variáveis entre chaves, vejo o pessoal utilizando o replace, vê se no link abaixo, isso fica mais claro.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443413/how-to-replace-strings-in-jquery-dom-element